# GNU screen: Utmp slot not found

Tags: display, centos

I've just had a dedicated server set up with the most minimal install of CentOS 7, and I just installed `screen`. When I run it under my normal user account, open a new screen window, and then go to close it, I'm greeted with this error: `Utmp slot not found -> not removed`. Maybe I'm being petty or obsessive, but this is driving me nuts. I read somewhere that you can use the `setutent` command to fix this error, but I don't even know where to find it, and the manpage suggests its only a function you use in C code. Is there anyone who could help this noobie figure out what the heck is going on?

Answer (score 11):

Open your `~/.screenrc` and paste the following line in there:

```
deflogin off
```

Then restart `screen`.

This will disable the utmp logging and thus get rid of the annoying message.

I've found this option in the [screen manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).

Answer (score 0):

utmp is a primitive database with info about users currently logged in (terminal, login time etc.) When a user logs out, the record corresponding to the username and the session's terminal gets deleted. So, although the message suggests a minor bug, it is not really serious.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This didn't happen on my CentOS 6 box. Is there a way to fix it? It's a huge nuisance.

Comment: CentOS often ships with really dated software. Try to build GNU Screen from the sources. Or use tmux.